# How to set locally heroku variables?

Tags: java, heroku

I am hosting a java application on heroku, and my `application-contextual-values.properties` contains many variable that are stored in my heroku dashboard.

So in my local, if I want to code, I always need to switch to local values, and comment them before deploying on my remote heroku app :

In my local (using eclipse) :

```
example.of.a.value=X <== this is the real value used on my code
```

When I am about to build my application I need to do this :

```
example.of.a.value=${EXAMPLE_OF_A_VALUE}
```

And in my heroku dashboard, I created a variable :

```
EXAMPLE_OF_A_VALUE : X
```

So Heroku is making the mapping needed to give X to my application.

How to avoid this comment/uncomment in my eclipse ?? is the a way to set in my machine the `EXAMPLE_OF_A_VALUE` and give "X" to it, and continue tu use localy ${EXAMPLE_OF_A_VALUE} ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The Heroku Config vars are environment variables that are made available to your application on both local environment (also running via the IDE) and on Heroku.

One approach is to define default values that work om your local environment (for development) then override them on Heroku to define the appropriate value.
This is nice as you don't need to setup anything when working locally (sometimes however you do not want to set defaults - ie passwords for example).

Another approach is to set the development values directly in ECLIPSE IDE (Run -> Run Configurations), see [Eclipse Environment Variable Setup Example](https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/desktop-java/ide/eclipse/eclipse-environment-variable-setup-example/)